# Common elements comparison between 2 lists

Tags: python, list

Given two input lists, how can I create a list of the elements that are common to both inputs?

For example: for inputs `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and `[3,5,7,9]`, the result should be `[3, 5]`; for inputs `['this','this','n','that']` and `['this','not','that','that']`, the result should be `['this', 'that']`.

---

**See also:**

- [In Python, how do I find common words from two lists while preserving word order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264471/) (to keep the order)
- [Python -Intersection of multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/) (for computing the intersection between >= 3 lists)
- [Intersection of two lists including duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/) (to keep the duplicate elements)

Comment: Hi, could you add some details on how you plan to use the code? If this is to complete an assignment, it may be better to choose a solution which encapsulates the "Pythonic" way. However, if efficiency is your concern, then the "Pythonic" way is unlikely to be the most efficient solution. Advising us on these details will help solutions aim to solve your problem.

Answer (score 505):

Use Python's [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list2 = [3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> list(set(list1).intersection(list2))
[3, 5]
```

Comment: +1 but personally I'd used frozenset as it's immutable and so can be used as dictionary key etc

Comment: This will return the /unique/ common elements, but not any repeated elements that may exist.

Comment: @SilentGhost. How to get the number of matched elements from two list. In this case it is 2.

Comment: @Poka len(list(set(list1).intersection(list2)))

Comment: FYI.  This is definitely faster, than the solution proposed by Tamás, but for the use case I was looking at when I ended up on this page, it was important to preserve the original order of the elements for the post-filtered elements.  This method loses the order, whereas the list comprehension method preserves the order.  Important if anyone needs to consider this.  Thanks.

Comment: A nice solution when you know the elements in the list are unique.

Comment: Is this the fastest method?

Comment: And don't forget you can use the `&` operator to make life easier too!  https://ioflood.com/blog/python-set-intersection/#:~:text=Python%20provides%20two%20main%20ways,()%20method%20and%20the%20%26%20operator.

Answer (score 51):

The solutions suggested by [S.Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists/2864867#2864867) and [SilentGhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists/2864863#2864863) generally tell you how it should be done in a Pythonic way, but I thought you might also benefit from knowing why your solution doesn't work. The problem is that as soon as you find the first common element in the two lists, you return that single element only. Your solution could be fixed by creating a `result` list and collecting the common elements in that list:

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for element in list1:
        if element in list2:
            result.append(element)
    return result
```

An even shorter version using list comprehensions:

```
def common_elements(list1, list2):
    return [element for element in list1 if element in list2]
```

However, as I said, this is a very inefficient way of doing this -- Python's built-in set types are way more efficient as they are implemented in C internally.

Comment: Great for both proposals

Comment: NOTE: The above methods will only work for equal sized lists. If you are working with unequal sized lists, as I am, then you will need to evaluate the order based on len() prior to calling the function:
list1 = [2,2,2], list2[2,3] -> [2,2,2]
list1 = [2,3], list2[2,2,2] -> [2]

Comment: As the author said: this just explains why the original approach failed (and I'm glad someone explained it). Conerning the equal sized lists: Even those won't guarantee the same result. Imagine `list1=[1,2]` and `list2=[2,2]`. Swap those lists and you get a different result.

Comment: Debugging OP's original approach to the problem is really a separate question, and not useful to others years later. I edited the question to remove that code attempt, because it was actively making the question worse as a reference canonical. There is now a separate canonical for the *problem OP was encountering* in writing the code: [How can I use `return` to get back multiple values from a loop? Can I put them in a list?](/questions/44564414)

Answer (score 47):

You can also use sets and get the commonalities in one line: subtract the set containing the differences from one of the sets.

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [2,4,7,8]
commonalities = set(A) - (set(A) - set(B))
```

Comment: This converts A to set twice, unnecessarily wasteful.

Answer (score 42):

You can solve this using [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = [3, 5, 7, 9]

common_elements = np.intersect1d(list1, list2)
print(common_elements)
```

`common_elements` will be the numpy array: `[3 5]`.

Answer (score 39):

use set intersections, set(list1) & set(list2)

```
>>> def common_elements(list1, list2):
...     return list(set(list1) & set(list2))
...
>>>
>>> common_elements([1,2,3,4,5,6], [3,5,7,9])
[3, 5]
>>>
>>> common_elements(['this','this','n','that'],['this','not','that','that'])
['this', 'that']
>>>
>>>
```

Note that result list could be different order with original list.

Comment: great solution. is there also a way to preserve the order with this?

Answer (score 21):

Set is another way we can solve this

```
a = [3,2,4]
b = [2,3,5]
set(a)&set(b)
{2, 3}
```

Comment: You can also frame this solution into list() to output as list: `list(set(a)&set(b))`

Comment: How does this add anything that wasn't already present in the initial round of answers from 2010?

Answer (score 15):

I compared each of method that each answer mentioned. At this moment I use python 3.6.3 for this implementation. This is the code that I have used:

```
import time
import random
from decimal import Decimal


def method1():
    common_elements = [x for x in li1_temp if x in li2_temp]
     print(len(common_elements))


def method2():
    common_elements = (x for x in li1_temp if x in li2_temp)
    print(len(list(common_elements)))


def method3():
    common_elements = set(li1_temp) & set(li2_temp)
    print(len(common_elements))


def method4():
    common_elements = set(li1_temp).intersection(li2_temp)
    print(len(common_elements))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    li1 = []
    li2 = []
    for i in range(100000):
        li1.append(random.randint(0, 10000))
        li2.append(random.randint(0, 10000))

    li1_temp = list(set(li1))
    li2_temp = list(set(li2))

    methods = [method1, method2, method3, method4]
    for m in methods:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        m()
        end = time.perf_counter()
        print(Decimal((end - start)))
```

If you run this code you can see that if you use list or generator(if you iterate over generator, not just use it. I did this when I forced generator to print length of it), you get nearly same performance. But if you use set you get much better performance. Also if you use intersection method you will get a little bit better performance. the result of each method in my computer is listed bellow:

1. method1: 0.8150673999999999974619413478649221360683441
2. method2: 0.8329545000000001531148541289439890533685684
3. method3: 0.0016547000000000089414697868051007390022277
4. method4: 0.0010262999999999244948867271887138485908508

Answer (score 11):

The previous answers all work to find the unique common elements, but will fail to account for repeated items in the lists. If you want the common elements to appear in the same number as they are found in common on the lists, you can use the following one-liner:

```
l2, common = l2[:], [ e for e in l1 if e in l2 and (l2.pop(l2.index(e)) or True)]
```

The `or True` part is only necessary if you expect any elements to evaluate to `False`.

Comment: This should be the answer that should have been selected! I am assuming it also works for unequal lists. Also most of the solutions use `set` which is not stable (aka the order is lost).

Comment: This solution's runtime is at least O(len(l1)*len(l2)) (that's not considering the cost of pop and index (e))

Comment: It's not a good practice to use mutable (with side effect) statements in list comprehension. Besides this is inefficient, [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430864/5267751) is better both regarding maintainability and runtime.

Comment: Looking around, there are already good methods to retain the duplicates. See [python - Intersection of two lists including duplicates? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645053/intersection-of-two-lists-including-duplicates#comments-37645155)

Comment: @user202729 yes, anyway, I would say the cannonical way to do this is to use `Counter`, which can act as a multiset, and indeed, even implements this with the `&` operator, so all you need is `list((Counter(list1) & Counter(list2)).elements())` and even if that wasn't built in you'd want to use a hash-map based approach...

Answer (score 1):

1) Method1
saving list1 is dictionary and then iterating each elem in list2

```
def findarrayhash(a,b):
    h1={k:1 for k in a}
    for val in b:
        if val in h1:
            print("common found",val)
            del h1[val]
        else:
            print("different found",val)
    for key in h1.iterkeys():
        print ("different found",key)
```

Finding Common and Different elements:

2) Method2
using set

```
def findarrayset(a,b):
    common = set(a)&set(b)
    diff=set(a)^set(b)
    print list(common)
    print list(diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions here that do it in O(l1+l2) that don't count repeating items, and slow solutions (at least O(l1*l2), but probably more expensive) that do consider repeating items.

So I figured I should add an O(l1*log(l1)+l2*(log(l2)) solution. This is particularly useful if the lists are already sorted.

```
def common_elems_with_repeats(first_list, second_list):
    first_list = sorted(first_list)
    second_list = sorted(second_list)
    marker_first = 0
    marker_second = 0
    common = []
    while marker_first < len(first_list) and marker_second < len(second_list):
        if(first_list[marker_first] == second_list[marker_second]):
            common.append(first_list[marker_first])
            marker_first +=1
            marker_second +=1
        elif first_list[marker_first] > second_list[marker_second]:
            marker_second += 1
        else:
            marker_first += 1
    return common
```

Another faster solution would include making a item->count map from list1, and iterating through list2, while updating the map and counting dups. Wouldn't require sorting. Would require extra a bit extra memory but it's technically O(l1+l2).

Answer (score 1):

If list1 and list2 are unsorted:

Using intersection:

```
print((set(list1)).intersection(set(list2)))
```

Combining the lists and checking if occurrence of an element is more than 1:

```
combined_list = list1 + list2
set([num for num in combined_list if combined_list.count(num) > 1])
```

Similar to above but without using set:

```
for num in combined_list:
    if combined_list.count(num) > 1:
        print(num)
        combined_list.remove(num)
```

For sorted lists, without python special built ins, an O(n) solution

```
p1 = 0
p2 = 0
result = []
while p1 < len(list1) and p2 < len(list2):
    if list1[p1] == list2[p2]:
        result.append(list1[p1])
        p1 += 1
        p2 += 2
    elif list1[p1] > list2[p2]:
        p2 += 1
    else:
        p1 += 1
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator:

```
common = (x for x in list1 if x in list2)
```

The advantage here is that this will return the generator in constant time (nearly instant) even when using huge lists or other huge iterables.

For example,

```
list1 =  list(range(0,10000000))
list2=list(range(1000,20000000))
common = (x for x in list1 if x in list2)
```

All other answers here will take a very long time with these values for list1 and list2.

You can then iterate the answer with

```
for i in common: print(i)
```

Comment: This does not produce an answer. The result is a generator rather than the list of common elements.

Comment: Correct, it creates a generator, which is an answer.  The question was to somehow get the common elements of the 2 lists, which this generator does.  Simply iterate the generator like so: `for i in common: print(i)`.  Generators are iterables that are frequently used in place of other iterables such as lists.

Comment: *"The advantage here is that this will return in constant time"* - so? This will return *the generator* in constant time. If you want the actual data you still need to convert to a list or iterate which will take the exact amount of time like the other solutions...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, yeah, I never suggested otherwise.  The advantage is with using the generator.  Maybe you don't need to iterate the entire list.  It entirely depends on your use-case.  If you convert it to a list then there is obviously no advantage.

Answer (score 0):

i have worked out a full solution for deep intersection

```
def common_items_dict(d1, d2, use_set_for_list_commons=True, use_set_for_dict_key_commons=True, append_empty=False):
    result = {}
    if use_set_for_dict_key_commons:
        shared_keys=list(set(d1.keys()).intersection(d2.keys())) # faster, order not preserved
    else:
        shared_keys=common_items_list(d1.keys(), d2.keys(), use_set_for_list_commons=False)

    for k in  shared_keys:
        v1 = d1[k]
        v2 = d2[k]
        if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
            result_dict=common_items_dict(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
            if len(result_dict)>0 or append_empty:
                result[k] = result_dict 
        elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
            result_list=common_items_list(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
            if len(result_list)>0 or append_empty:
                result[k] = result_list 
        elif v1 == v2:
            result[k] = v1
    return result

def common_items_list(d1, d2, use_set_for_list_commons=True, use_set_for_dict_key_commons=True, append_empty=False):
    if use_set_for_list_commons: 
        result_list= list(set(d2).intersection(d1)) # faster, order not preserved, support only simple data types in list values
        return result_list

    result = []
    for v1 in d1: 
        for v2 in d2:
            if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
                result_dict=common_items_dict(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
                if len(result_dict)>0 or append_empty:
                    result.append(result_dict)
            elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
                result_list=common_items_list(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
                if len(result_list)>0 or append_empty:
                    result.append(result_list)
            elif v1 == v2:
                result.append(v1)
    return result


def deep_commons(v1,v2, use_set_for_list_commons=True, use_set_for_dict_key_commons=True, append_empty=False):
    """
    deep_commons
     returns intersection of items of dict and list combinations recursively

    this function is a starter function, 
    i.e. if you know that the initial input is always dict then you can use common_items_dict directly
    or if it is a list you can use common_items_list directly

    v1 - dict/list/simple_value
    v2 - dict/list/simple_value
    use_set_for_dict_key_commons - bool - using set is faster, dict key order is not preserved 
    use_set_for_list_commons - bool - using set is faster, list values order not preserved, support only simple data types in list values
    append_empty - bool - if there is a common key, but no common items in value of key , if True it keeps the key with an empty list of dict

    """

    if isinstance(v1, dict) and isinstance(v2, dict):
        return common_items_dict(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
    elif isinstance(v1, list) and isinstance(v2, list):
        return common_items_list(v1, v2, use_set_for_list_commons, use_set_for_dict_key_commons, append_empty)
    elif v1 == v2:
        return v1
    else:
        return None


needed_services={'group1':['item1','item2'],'group3':['item1','item2']}
needed_services2={'group1':['item1','item2'],'group3':['item1','item2']}

result=deep_commons(needed_services,needed_services2)

print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
list1=[123,324523,5432,311,23]
list2=[2343254,34234,234,322123,123,234,23]
common=[]
def common_elements(list1,list2):
    for x in range(0,len(list1)):
        if list1[x] in list2:
            common.append(list1[x])
            
common_elements(list1,list2)
print(common)
```

Comment: That's the same code as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists/2865033#2865033. You just created a bad version of it by using an unpythonic index access. Additionally you made it even worse by using a global variable in the function.