# Python -Intersection of multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, set, intersection

I am playing with python and am able to get the intersection of two lists:

```
result = set(a).intersection(b)
```

Now if `d` is a list containing `a` and `b` and a third element `c`, is there an built-in function for finding the intersection of all the three lists inside `d`? So for instance,

```
d = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5,6,7]]
```

then the result should be

```
[3,4]
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

for 2.4, you can just define an intersection function.

```
def intersect(*d):
    sets = iter(map(set, d))
    result = sets.next()
    for s in sets:
        result = result.intersection(s)
    return result
```

---

for newer versions of python:

the intersection method takes an arbitrary amount of arguments

```
result = set(d[0]).intersection(*d[1:])
```

alternatively, you can intersect the first set with itself to avoid slicing the list and making a copy:

```
result = set(d[0]).intersection(*d)
```

I'm not really sure which would be more efficient and have a feeling that it would depend on the size of the `d[0]` and the size of the list unless python has an inbuilt check for it like

```
if s1 is s2:
    return s1
```

in the intersection method.

```
>>> d = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5,6,7]]
>>> set(d[0]).intersection(*d)
set([3, 4])
>>> set(d[0]).intersection(*d[1:])
set([3, 4])
>>>
```

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: It gives me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'intersection'` if I do that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Legend. you have to map it to a set first. I somehow missed the fact that they were lists. After that, you can just pass lists (or any other iterable) to the `intersection` method

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Actually, not sure why but I'm getting this error no matter what solution I try: `TypeError: intersection() takes exactly one argument (3 given)`

Comment: @Legend. both my answer and TokenMacGuy's work for me on python 2.6 and 3.1

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Aah... Is there some solution for Python 2.4 by any chance?

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Today's a bad day. Sorry. When I define the intersection, it gives me: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'set' referenced before assignment` I don't understand why it is considering set as a local variable.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: I edited your answer to something that works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Legend. Thanks for cleaning up my post. but remember: 'Thus spoke the Lord: "Thou shalt indent with four spaces. No more, no less. Four shall be the number of spaces thou shalt indent, and the number of thy indenting shall be four. Eight shalt thou not indent, nor either indent thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to four. Tabs are the devil's apples!"'

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth: Aye aye captain! Thou shall remember that for next time... Thanks! :)

Comment: Lobbeth thou thy holy space bar of Antioch.

Comment: I believe you made a typo:
`result = set(d[0]).intersection(*d[:1])`
should be:
`result = set(d[0]).intersection(*d[1:])`. Otherwise you're just getting the first list back.

Answer (score 127):

```
set.intersection(*map(set,d))
```

Comment: Not sure what's wrong here. Now it gives me: `TypeError: intersection() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 for that. I just couldn't use it because of my Python version :(

Comment: If the `d` variable may have a length of zero the `set.intersection` function will raise a `TypeError` exception. I would recommend catching that exception and return `set()` (an empty set) instead in that degenerate case. This is better than checking the `len` of `d` beforehand as it may be a generator.

Comment: @AaronR: Good point, but the degenerate solution for set intersection is the universal set, not the empty set.  since there's no compact way to represent that in python, raising an exception (probably catching the type error and raising something more sensible) is still probably the right way to handle it.  Returning an empty set *is* the right thing to do for set union, however.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Yes, you're quite right; by analogy with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product it would be the only set which would be guaranteed to not change the result of an intersection.

Comment: This is briliant but a further explanation would be appreciated and useful.

Comment: @CesareIurlaro It's a built-in function... Documentation link => [Built-in Types — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection)

Answer (score 12):

@user3917838

Nice and simple but needs some casting to make it work and give a list as a result. It should look like:

```
list(reduce(set.intersection, [set(item) for item in d ]))
```

where:

```
d = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5,6,7]]
```

And result is:

```
[3, 4]
```

At least in Python 3.4

Answer (score 12):

You can get the intersection of an arbitrary number sets using `set.intersection(set1, set2, set3...)`.  So you just need to convert your lists into sets and then pass them to this method as follows:

```
d = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [3,4,5,6,7]]  
set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in d])
```

result:

```
{3, 4}
```

Answer (score 4):

I find `reduce()` to be particularly useful. In fact, the `numpy` documents recommend using `reduce()` to intersect multiple lists: [numpy.intersect1d reference](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html)

To answer your question:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
# apply intersect1d to (a list of) multiple lists:
reduce(np.intersect1d, [list_1, list_2, ... list_n])
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambda reduce.

```
from functools import reduce #you won't need this in Python 2
l=[[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
reduce(set.intersection, [set(l_) for l_ in l])
```

Comment: you require a list of set , this would fail saying that 'descriptor intersection requires set'