# Intersection of variable number of lists

Tags: python, list, function, set, intersection

I define intersection of two lists as follows:

```
def intersect(a, b):
  return list(set(a) & set(b))
```

For three arguments it would look like:

```
def intersect(a, b, c):
  return (list(set(a) & set(b) & set(c))
```

Can I generalize this function for variable number of lists?

The call would look for example like:

```
>> intersect([1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 5, 2], [2, 7, 2])
[2]
```

EDIT: Python can only achieve it this way?

```
intersect([
          [1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 5, 2], [2, 7, 2]
         ])
[2]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how best do I find the intersection of multiple sets in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541752/how-best-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-multiple-sets-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python -Intersection of multiple lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists)

Comment: why has this been upvoted? It is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @jamylak My question is different. I want to extend my function for more arguments (unknown number of arguments).

Comment: did you see the second link? That is exactly your question

Comment: @jamylak Title is similar, but question is different.

Comment: Nope, it is **exactly** the same, the answer posted here is also listed on that question. -_-

Comment: @jamylak OK, I didn't realized this. It's really very similar.

Comment: hahaha good. It was very hard convincing you :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`*`-list-to-argument operator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and instead of your custom function use `set.intersection`:

```
>>> lists = [[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 2], [2, 5, 2], [2, 7, 2]]
>>> list(set.intersection(*map(set, lists)))
[2]
```

If you want the list-to-set-to-list logic inside a function, you can do it like this:

```
def intersect(lists):
    return list(set.intersection(*map(set, lists)))
```

If you prefer `intersect()` to accept an arbitrary number of arguments instead of a single one, use this instead:

```
def intersect(*lists):
    return list(set.intersection(*map(set, lists)))
```

Comment: You don't actually need to setify every list, only the first one - `set(lists[0]).intersection(*lists)` will do the same thing. Not that this is necessarily a good idea, since it is somewhat less readable, but it might be slightly more efficient for very large numbers of lists.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Python can only take an argument as a list? can't it take variable number of arguments?

Comment: @xralf: If you want `intersect()` to accept multiple arguments, use `def intersect(*lists)`. Then `lists` will be a list containing all positional arguments.

Comment: This is not a good solution. It fails when `lists` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
def intersect(*lists):
    if(len(lists) <=1):
        return lists[0]

    result = lists[0]
    for i in range(1, len(lists)):
        result = set(result) & set(lists[i])

    return list(result)
```

Call the function just like this...

```
intersect([1,2],[2,3],[2,4])
```

Leaving all sanitation to you.

Comment: It is not very pythonic, iterating over a list using the index shouldn't ever need to be used in Python.