# I am trying to find the set of lists in a tuple

Tags: python

for example,

```
(['2', '3', '5'], ['1', '3', '4', '5'])
```

the above should yield the numbers 3 and 5

```
(['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '2'])
```

this should give out 1 , 2

```
(['2', '3', '5'], ['1', '2', '4'], ['2', '3'])
```

this, should give out 2, because 2 is contained in all 3 lists in the tuple. If there is no set it should just return an empty list

```
for i,e in enumerate(tup):
while index < len(tup):
    print(tup[index], tup[index + 1])
    index = index + 1
```

For now i have this, i am not sure how to go through the tup(Tuple) and extract each list to find the set of each 2 lists and iterate and compare with the rest of lists in the tuple

Comment: `because 2 is contained in all 3 lists in the tuple`, but `4` is not contained in both lists in the first tuple. What's the logic here?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget my mistake i will edit it

Comment: Why should it return and empty string by default? Why not just a list with no elements? The output type is not very clear

Comment: @FlavianHautbois sure either one is fine, but i was going to use the output for a map so it shouldn't matter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def intersect(lists):
    return list(set.intersection(*map(set, lists)))
```

Comment: I like this answer best since it's clean and it handles variable number of lists

Comment: @timgeb intersection needs sets and not lists ... you can do a list comprehension instead but i think you still need to convert them to sets

Comment: @JulienSpronck you are right, I misread. You can use `intersection` on an existing set without converting the arguments to sets (see my answer).

Comment: @timgeb fair enough :-)

Comment: Kind of stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10861236/intersection-of-variable-number-of-lists though

Answer (score 3):

```
In [8]: t = (['2', '3', '5'], ['1', '3', '4', '5'])

In [9]: functools.reduce(lambda a,b: set.intersection(set(a), set(b)), t)
Out[9]: {'3', '5'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be consistent in return types. Don't return an empty string when you have an empty set.

That being said, I'd find the numbers like this:

```
>>> lsts = (['2', '3', '5'], ['1', '3', '4', '5'])
>>> set(lsts[0]).intersection(*lsts[1:])
set(['3', '5'])
>>> 
>>> lsts = (['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '2'])
>>> set(lsts[0]).intersection(*lsts[1:])
set(['1', '2'])
>>> 
>>> lsts = (['2', '3', '5'], ['1', '2', '4'], ['2', '3'])
>>> set(lsts[0]).intersection(*lsts[1:])
set(['2'])
```

The function for that would be:

```
>>> def common(lsts):
...     return set() if not lsts else set(lsts[0]).intersection(*lsts[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple as that: python has a set type, so just

```
sets = [set(l) for l in (['2', '3', '5'], ['1', '3', '4', '5']) ]
common_elements = reduce(lambda a,b: a & b, sets)
```