# intersection of lists called from defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to find the intersection of lists that are stored within the `defaultdict(list)` container. Here is my dictionary, `'d'` a list of lookup values, 'my_list':

```
d = { a: ['1', '2', '3'],
      b: ['3', '4', '5'],
      c: ['3', '6', '7']
     }

my_list = ['a', 'b']
```

I would like to return the intersection of the lists. Based on a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists) I tried the following but get an error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

```
set.intersection(*map(set,d[my_list]))
```

any suggestions would be welcome.

thanks,
zach cp

Comment: Your first two lines don't do anything because you just reassign `d` straight after

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access `d[my_list]` – a list is not a vlaid dictionary key.  One alternative:

```
set.intersection(*(set(d[k]) for k in my_list))
```