# concordance for a phrase using NLTK in Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Is it possible to get concordance for a phrase in NLTK?

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

corpus_loc = "c://temp//text//"
files = ".*\.txt"
read_corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_loc, files)
corpus  = nltk.Text(read_corpus.words())
test = nltk.TextCollection(corpus_loc)

corpus.concordance("claim")
```

for example the above returns

```
on okay okay okay i can give you the claim number and my information and
 decide on the shop okay okay so the claim number is xxxx - xx - xxxx got
```

and now if I try `corpus.concordance("claim number")` it does not work... I do have the code to do this with just by using `.partition()` method and some further coding on the same... but I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same using `concordance`.

Comment: NLTK.text.concordance seems to only take a single word. However, an option would be to replace 'claim number' by 'claim_number' in both texts and get a concordance for 'claim_number'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/90) it is not (yet) possible to search for multiple words with the `concordance()` function.

Answer (score 6):

If you read the discussion under the very [issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/90) that @b3000 dug up, you'll see that strangely enough, multi-word concordance is in fact available-- but only in the graphical concordance tool, which you can start up like this:

```
>>> from nltk.app import concordance
>>> concordance()
```

Answer (score 4):

I munged together this solution...

```
def n_concordance_tokenised(text,phrase,left_margin=5,right_margin=5):
    #concordance replication via https://simplypython.wordpress.com/2014/03/14/saving-output-of-nltk-text-concordance/

    phraseList=phrase.split(' ')

    c = nltk.ConcordanceIndex(text.tokens, key = lambda s: s.lower())

    #Find the offset for each token in the phrase
    offsets=[c.offsets(x) for x in phraseList]
    offsets_norm=[]
    #For each token in the phraselist, find the offsets and rebase them to the start of the phrase
    for i in range(len(phraseList)):
        offsets_norm.append([x-i for x in offsets[i]])
    #We have found the offset of a phrase if the rebased values intersect
    #--
    # http://stackoverflow.com/a/3852792/454773
    #the intersection method takes an arbitrary amount of arguments
    #result = set(d[0]).intersection(*d[1:])
    #--
    intersects=set(offsets_norm[0]).intersection(*offsets_norm[1:])

    concordance_txt = ([text.tokens[map(lambda x: x-left_margin if (x-left_margin)&gt;0 else 0,[offset])[0]:offset+len(phraseList)+right_margin]
                    for offset in intersects])

    outputs=[''.join([x+' ' for x in con_sub]) for con_sub in concordance_txt]
    return outputs

def n_concordance(txt,phrase,left_margin=5,right_margin=5):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(txt)
    text = nltk.Text(tokens)

    return

n_concordance_tokenised(text,phrase,left_margin=left_margin,right_margin=right_margin)

n_concordance_tokenised(text1,'monstrous size')
>> [u'one was of a most monstrous size . ... This came towards ',
    u'; for Whales of a monstrous size are oftentimes cast up dead ']
```