# extract and process 5grams in Python. NLTK API or alternative?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nltk

I want to extract natural language from google 5grams with a key word. Then I need to clean the results from stop words (prepositions, pronouns etc.). Next I want to replace the ‘language’ results with a number. I have an excel file with a large corpora of words and corresponding scores for that. In the end I want to run a (two-sided repeated) ANOVA.

I have found this useful script from [culturomics](https://github.com/theaidenlab/NgramScript/commit/9418890c1cb2d434eb5407971c3744ae386a2c91#diff-82ab8e7adf92a12796c5774100764fba) for python 2.x that does the first step. My input is "gemstone *_NOUN" (wildcard function for nouns only). This input needs to be repeated to cover most other content words; i.e. "gemstone* _VERB"  "...* _ADJ"  "...* _ADV". The output per input is a [tsv file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45457232/gemstone%2B%252A_NOUN-eng_2012-1958-2008-3.tsv). In row 3 I have the keyword with the result and the linguistic word category. So I need to get rid off the keyword & word category and store all results it in an accessible manner for further processing. Store in an python array?

Another possibility is to use the [concordance function](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) from the NLTK package to retrieve the desired words. Then use the clean stop word function (which I was told exists) and replace words with numbers. But I haven’t pursued this option.

Before I continue I thought I’d ask. Is there another script available that I could leverage? Being  new to Python, which approach is better?

I am looking to retrieve the results of 40 keywords, which gives me 200 words from google 5grams. Ideally I would like to adapt and apply the script for Twitter and other secondary data. 
Many thanks!

Comment: Google `KenLM` also see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/util.py#L416

Comment: Thanks alvas! Will have a look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will go with option A (tweak existing culturomics script) and/or Alvas suggestions. The concordance function only reads .txt and .xml files (so cannot actually read an URL input) and only allows for a single word input. This might be up-dated in future. There seems to be a graphical solution for multiple word input according to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33813405/concordance-for-a-phrase-using-nltk-in-python#). I could certainly try to use the [concordance crawler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConcordanceCrawler) (haven't looked at it in-depth though) to gather the data, write the results to a compatible file and then start the analysis. But this adds another step in the script and I am not convinced about the use of that.