# Python 3.4 set intersection

Tags: python, python-3.x, set-intersection

I am trying to understand why my intersection does not return an empty list when I run this code.

```
n = ([1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[5,6,7],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[10,22,33,44,45])
w = set(n[0]).intersection(*n[:1])
print(w)
#Returns (1,2,3,4,5)
```

However this returns the correct set

```
n = ([1,2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[5,6,7],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[10,22,33,44,45])
w = set(n[0]).intersection(*n)
print(w)
#Returns empty set.
```

This question gave the correct results for both:
[Python -Intersection of multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists)

Why do I not get the correct result when I compare the first set to the remaining lists?

Comment: `set.intersection(*map(set, n)` would be a more memory efficient way to do what you want.

Comment: Padraic.  I have not looked at memory but your method is about 30% slower.  1.5 to 1.7 seconds per 100,000 searches vs 0.9 to 1.0 seconds for what I was attempting.

Comment: yes that is why I said more memory efficient, it is not always possible to make copies of data so sometimes memory is more important than speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*n[:1]` unpacks to `(n[0],)` - the first element of the set.

So you're intersecting `n[0]` with itself, and the result is what you see. You probably intended to write

```
set(n[0]).intersection(*n[1:])
```

Comment: That was it.  I cannot believe I made that mistake.  Thank you.