# searching similar columns names in multiple dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple datasets which has same columns name as below example, I want the columns which are repeated in multiple datasets sort out in list format using python and pandas.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8), 
               'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'C': np.arange(8)})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
               'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
               'D': np.arange(8) * 2})
```

As from above we can see in three Datasets df1, df2, df3 has repeated columns as 'A', 'B' and the output as ['A', 'B']
Please can give solution to this problem.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas can [get list of column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482970/get-list-from-pandas-dataframe-column-headers) for you. For example,`df1.columns` will return `['A','B','C','D']`. Likewise you can get the list of column names for each dataframe.

Then you can just [find out the intersection of all these lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists).

Answer (score 0):

Pandas columns are of type `pandas.core.indexes.base.Index` you could use the intersection function in them to find the overlapping elements. Here is an example below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1,4)
b = np.arange(5,8)
c = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
d = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c,'d':d})

out:

    a   b   c   d
0   1   5   5   1
1   2   6   7   5
2   3   7   6   9

a = np.arange(4,7)
b = np.arange(7,10)
e = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
f = np.random.randint(0,10,size=3)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'e':c,'f':d})
df_2

out:

    a   b   e   f
0   4   7   9   9
1   5   8   9   3
2   6   9   2   1

df_1.columns.intersection(df_2.columns)

out:

Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')

type(df_1.columns)

out:

pandas.core.indexes.base.Index
```

Answer (score 0):

I think simpliest is `&` for intersection of all columns names:

```
a = df1.columns & df2.columns & df3.columns
print (a)
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

If need `list`:

```
a = (df1.columns & df2.columns & df3.columns).tolist()
print (a)
['A', 'B']
```