# Compare multiple lists inside a list Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is it possible to compare a list containing an unknown number of lists with equal elements in a more terse (aka shorter) manner than what I have done? Preferably an one-liner!

Here's an example if it's unclear what I want to do:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 2, 1]
c = [7, 5, 1]
d = [a, b, c]

def multiCompList(lists):
    final = [i for i in lists[0] if i in lists[1]]
    for i in range(2, len(lists)):
        final = [i for i in final if i in lists[i]]

    return final

print(multiCompList(d))
```

What I've done is to first check if the first and second list contains any equal elements and put them in a list called final. Thereafter, checking if those elements can be found in the lists after and replacing the final-list with the remaining equal elements.
The results in this case is: [1].

Comment: you want to find the intersection of all the lists? does the order matter?

Comment: @Chris_Rands No I guess intersection of first two lists and third to nth list intersection. So not mere intersection of all the list

Comment: Perhaps you can apply your learning from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists

Comment: You sample example and explanation is tangential. DO u want to get common values from all the lists?

Comment: Thank you @RahulChawla. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner would look like this:

```
set.intersection(*[set(x) for x in d])
#set([1])
```