# Avoid for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there a way to avoid this for loop in favor of efficiency? I was thinking about iter/next functions but they don't seem to work properly..

```
def foo():
    lst = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
    res = set(lst[0])
    for word in lst:
        res = res.intersection(word)
    return ''.join(res)
```

Comment: You will have to first explain why you want to avoid the for loop. Without understanding your constraints, the answers can be only guesses.

Comment: What is `res`? It pops out of nowhere, without being initialized to anything

Comment: Also curious why you tagged python3 *and* python2...

Comment: And why is there a `return` without a function?

Comment: Can you also provide a sample of what `lst` might be? And what you expect the return value to be?

Comment: And now `lst` is?

Comment: just updated..@Guimoute is it necessary to write all the code? it's quite obvious that this part of code is inside a func

Comment: Not all the code, but a [mcve].

Comment: @EddyIT it is important to show relevant parts and since you want to discuss about efficiency we need to know what this is

Comment: sounds better now?

Answer (score 2):

`set.intersection` isn't limited to a single argument.

```
res = set(lst[0]).intersection(*lst[1:])
```

For example:

```
>>> foo = set([1,2,3])
>>> foo.intersection([1,2])
{1,2}
>>> foo.intersection([2,3])
{2,3}
>>> foo.intersection([1,2], [2,3])
{3}
```

Comment: Does `intersection` not expect only `set` arguments?

Comment: No; the arguments can be any iterables. (The *first*, implicit argument has to be a set, so `set.intersection([1,2], [2,3])` won't work, but `set.intersection(set([1,2]), [2,3])` is the same as `set([1,2]).intersection([2,3])`.)

Comment: This question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists

Comment: @whati001 So vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason I would feel better with something like `set.intersection(*(set(lst) for lst in list_of_lists))`. I don't like the idea needed an "irregular" first element to start the process.