# Find similar values in a list of lists

Tags: python

I know this question is asked a lot, but they are all used for different things.
**What I want to happen:**

```py
#python 3.9
list = [["grass", "sand", "water"],["rock", "grass", "sand"]]
matches = ["sand", "water"]
```

Is there a way to find matches this way?

Comment: Please elaborate. What is the goal? Identify which sublists contain the words in `matches` or just determine if they're there somewhere?

Comment: Don't used keyword list. Use this _list.

Comment: One line: `print(set.intersection(*map(set, my_list)))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python -Intersection of multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the lists into sets and take their intersection.  You can do this across an arbitrarily long list of sets in a single line with `functools.reduce`:

```
>>> my_list = [["grass", "sand", "water"],["rock", "grass", "sand"]]
>>> import functools
>>> functools.reduce(set.intersection, map(set, my_list))
{'grass', 'sand'}
```