# Find all values in a list which match in a dictionary?

Tags: python

lets say I have the following dictionary

```
dict1= {"a":[1,2,3],"b":[2,3,4]}
```

how would I make it so the output is:

```
[2,3]
```

where the values match in a dictionary.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you walk us through what you have tried so far and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Are you asking [how to compute the intersection of multiple lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852780/python-intersection-of-multiple-lists) Or are you having trouble accessing the lists in the dictionary at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer to my code bellow:

```
arr1 = d['a']
arr2 = d['b']
arrResult = []
for i in arr1:
  if i in arr2:
    arrResult.append(i)
print(arrResult)
```

and here is the result: `[2, 3]`

More advanced you can use:

```
x = set.intersection(*map(set, d.values()))    
print(x)
```

Comment: Great! What would happen if we had infinite number of keys and tried to find the intersection of the values in the keys?

Comment: I have added, you can refer on my reply. if found helpful, rate my answer to help the next person. Thanks!