# common elements in two lists python

Tags: python, list

I have two python lists generated from two different database tables

```
list1= ["'HZ1398043','HZ1395693','HZ1395532','HZ1395240','HZ1395194','HZ1395113','HZ1395036','HZ1395236','HZ1396139','HZ1398028','HZ1395098','HZ1395998','HZ1395018','HZ1395829','HZ1398031','HZ1395708','HZ1398029','HZ1398030','HZ1398054''"]

list2= ['', '', '', '', '', 'HZ1395018', 'HZ1395036', 'HZ1395098', 'HZ1395113', 'HZ1395194', 'HZ1395236', 'HZ1395240', 'HZ1395532', 'HZ1395693', 'HZ1395708', 'HZ1395829', 'HZ1395998', 'HZ1396139', 'HZ1398028', 'HZ1398029', 'HZ1398031', 'HZ1398043', 'HZ1397932', 'HZ1397949', 'HZ1398004', 'HZ1398021', 'HZ1398030', 'HZ1397940', 'HZ1397941', 'HZ1398010',', '', '']
```

I need to find common elements between the two

```
set(list1) & set(list2)
```

doesn't display anything

even `[i for i in list1 if i in list2]` doesn't display anything. I can clearly see HZ1398043 is common.

Comment: For the question in title: [python - Common elements comparison between 2 lists - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look closely, your first list is actually a list with one item, a big string.

```
>>> list1= ["'HZ1398043','HZ1395693','HZ1395532','HZ1395240','HZ1395194','HZ1395113','HZ1395036','HZ1395236','HZ1396139','HZ1398028','HZ1395098','HZ1395998','HZ1395018','HZ1395829','HZ1398031','HZ1395708','HZ1398029','HZ1398030','HZ1398054''"]
>>> len(list1)
1
```

Ideally, fix wherever you are getting the data to give you the right thing, if that's not possible, then you will need to parse the data.

You will want to do something like `list1 = [item.strip("'") for item in list1[0].split(",")]` to get the actual list (a simple [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw)), then use one of your methods (the set method is the most efficient, although if you wish the keep duplicates and order, you will need to do the second method, although you can improve it by making a set of `list2` beforehand to check for membership in).

Comment: Oh yaa.. how do I split them into multiple items

Comment: I was editing the question, and came to know the answer that list1 actually contains a single element and its a string. I came back quickly and you pointed out already :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to make a proper list out of list1, this can be done with something like:

```
list1 = [item.strip("'") for item in list1[0].split(",")]
```

Then your code should work just fine.
An alternative (more compact but slower) way to find common elements would be:

```
common = filter(lambda x:x in list1,list2)
```

Comment: o_O not quite sure what is wrong with this answer...thx for comments I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is what they *should* be:

```
list1= ['HZ1398043','HZ1395693','HZ1395532','HZ1395240','HZ1395194','HZ1395113','HZ1395036','HZ1395236','HZ1396139','HZ1398028','HZ1395098','HZ1395998','HZ1395018','HZ1395829','HZ1398031','HZ1395708','HZ1398029','HZ1398030','HZ1398054']
list2= ['', '', '', '', '', 'HZ1395018', 'HZ1395036', 'HZ1395098', 'HZ1395113', 'HZ1395194', 'HZ1395236', 'HZ1395240', 'HZ1395532', 'HZ1395693', 'HZ1395708', 'HZ1395829', 'HZ1395998', 'HZ1396139', 'HZ1398028', 'HZ1398029', 'HZ1398031', 'HZ1398043', 'HZ1397932', 'HZ1397949', 'HZ1398004', 'HZ1398021', 'HZ1398030', 'HZ1397940', 'HZ1397941', 'HZ1398010','', '', '']
```

Your code works after you fix them.

Answer (score 1):

```
def compare(list1,list2):
ln= []
for i in list1:
    if i  in list2:
       ln.append(i)
return ln
```

print(compare(list1,list2))

not optimise but easy to understand.