# In Python, how do I find common words from two lists while preserving word order?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find an easy way to do this:

```
list1 = ['little','blue','widget']
list2 = ['there','is','a','little','blue','cup','on','the','table']
```

I want to get common elements of the two lists, with list1's order untouched, so this result is expected.

```
list3 = ['little','blue']
```

I am using

```
list3 = list(set(list1)&set(list2))
```

however, this only returns `list3 =  ['blue', 'little']`, obviously, set() just ignore the order.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were almost there, just sort `list3` according to `list1`

```
list1 = ['little','blue','widget']
list2 = ['there','is','a','little','blue','cup','on','the','table']

list3 = set(list1)&set(list2) # we don't need to list3 to actually be a list

list4 = sorted(list3, key = lambda k : list1.index(k))
```

Result:

```
>>> list4
['little', 'blue']
```

Comment: This is not as efficient as the [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18264481/5267751), as it have to compute `list1.index` (takes linear time) for each element in `list3`.

Answer (score 6):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> list1 = ['little','blue','widget']
>>> list2 = ['there','is','a','little','blue','cup','on','the','table']
>>> s = set(list2)
>>> list3 = [x for x in list1 if x in s]
>>> list3
['little', 'blue']
```

Comment: Are you converting list2 to a set first because sets are faster to search, or is there another reason?

Comment: @Brionius, Converting `list2` for the search speed. No other reason.

Comment: What if `list1 = ['little','blue','widget', 'little']`? Then your method would produce `['little', 'blue', 'little']`.

Comment: @Akavall, If you want `['little', 'blue']`, use `[x for x in OrderedDict.fromkeys(list1) if x in s]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using filter:

```
list1 = ['little','blue','widget']
list2 = ['there','is','a','little','blue','cup','on','the','table']
set2 = set(list2)
f = lambda x:x in set2

list3 = filter(f, list1)
```

Comment: Just for the record, the list comprehension method is about 70% faster than the filter method.

Answer (score 0):

This does what your asking for using python 2.7, not particularly elegant but it does answer your question.

```
list1 = ['little','blue','widget']
list2 = ['there','is','a','little','blue','cup','on','the','table']
list3 = []
for l1 in list1:
    for l2 in list2:
        if l2 == l1:
            list3.append(l2)

print list3  # ['little', 'blue']
```