# find UnRepeated word in two list

Tags: python

i Have different words in two lists and also i have a commit words 
i need to get out the different words in two lists
for Example list one:

```
apple
cut
chance
```

list two :

```
apple
cut
chance
help
there
```

my shot not working it give me repeated and there is unrepeated words 
my script

```
wcode = open('wcode.txt', 'r')
rcode = open('rcode.txt', 'r')
for new in wcode :
    if wcode.read() in rcode.read() :
        print(' Repeated ')
    else :
        print(' UnRepeated !!!' + '\n' + new)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264471/in-python-how-do-i-find-common-words-from-two-lists-while-preserving-word-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I find common words from two lists while preserving word order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264471/in-python-how-do-i-find-common-words-from-two-lists-while-preserving-word-order)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between the two lists.  For finding this, I would use Python's [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) operations.

After you've read the contents of yours files into lists, you can convert them to sets and compute the symmetric difference as shown below.  At the end, you can convert the result back to a list if you want.

```
wcode = ['a', 'list', 'of', 'words', 'that', 'you', 'read', 'from', 'wcode', 'txt']
rcode = ['a', 'list', 'of', 'words', 'that', 'she', 'read', 'from', 'rcode', 'txt']
wcode = set(wcode)
rcode = set(rcode)

difference = wcode.symmetric_difference(rcode)

assert difference == {'she', 'you', 'wcode', 'rcode'}
final_result = list(difference)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sets:

```
s1 = {"apple", "cut", "chance"}
s2 = {"apple", "cut", "chance", "help", "there"}

print("Repeated: " + ", ".join(s1 & s2))
print("Not repeated: " + ", ".join(s1.symmetric_difference(s2)))
```

**Edit**

The bigger issue is that you should probably be consuming your files very differently:

```
wcode, rcode = (set(open(fn, "rb").read().splitlines()) for fn in [
    "rcode.txt",
    "wcode.txt"])
```

Comment: The big loss here is you don't preserve the order of the lists. Whether that's relevant is a question that must be asked of the OP.