# Get common (not repeated) elements among 2 lists using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose you have 2 lists [Python 3.x]:

```
x=[2,2,3,4,5,5,6]
y=[2,3,5,9,11]
```

What I want to accomplish is I want to get the common elements among the 2 lists, without getting repeated elements, only using list comprehension. I hope its possible ?!

In other threads, I have seen the following list comprehension that kinda does the job but returns the repeated elements as well:

```
>>> x=[2,2,3,4,5,5,6]
>>> y=[2,3,5,9,11]
>>> z=[t for t in x if t in y]
>>> z
[2, 2, 3, 5, 5]
```

I know there are many solutions to get common elements between 2 lists. The most common solution is doing a set intersection, which gets exactly what I want, without the repeated elements. But I want to accomplish this only using list comprehension, as I said before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since `set` does the job by its very nature, *why* do you want to use only list comprehension?  This suggests that you're dumping homework or quiz problems on us without the required effort.

Comment: `[x for x in range(0)] or set(x) & set(y)` meeting the requirement for a comprehension ;)

Comment: Don't make it hard on yourself by learning to do something the wrong way. Use the tools available to you that are most appropriate. Use set() and call it a day.

Comment: Nope @Prune I dont have any sorta homework right now thats related to this. This was just outta curiosity, coz I dont know very much about list comprehension and there isnt much documentation out there about this. Most of the time I get syntax error when I try anything else than for and if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the extra work, you can step through the range of values:

```
z = [t for t in range(min(x), max(x)+1) if t in x and t in y]
```

This iterates over the range of one list, considering each value exactly once.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! This does the job without typecasting *anything* into a set, which is pretty much what I wanted to see.

Comment: Just a word of caution: This will only work for integer elements. If you have `2.0` in `x` and `2` in `y`, this method fails.

Comment: @Bazingaa quite correct; this works only for a discrete, well-ordered data type ... actually only those for which a `range` iteration is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set`

```
x=[2,2,3,4,5,5,6]
y=[2,3,5,9,11]
z=list(set([t for t in x if t in y]))
print (z)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Ah perfect! Being a beginner I didnt think bout it. Thanks! But still, can we do this right in the list comprehension,  without typecasting anything to a set? Just out of curiosity ;)

Comment: Yup I need to wait for 3 more mins.

Comment: Well here's a solution without using `set`: `answer = [e for e in x if e in y and (y.pop(y.index(e)) or True)]`. Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists