# How to join two lists based on the list element occurrence of one of the two using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have the following lists

```
list1 = [[x1,1,b1],[x2,1,b1],[x3,1,b1],[x4,1,b1]]
```

and the following

```
list2 = [[x1,0,b1],[x5,0,b1],[x2,0,b1],[x7,0,b1]]
```

I don't know how to create a final list like the

```
list3 = [[x1,1,b1],[x2,1,b1],[x3,1,b1],[x4,1,b1],[x5,0,b1],[x7,0,b1]]
```

To keep the first list1 and add to list1 elements from list2 
only if the list2[0][0] element does not exist in list1

I tried something like the following with several combinations

```
for i in list1:
    for i2 in list2:
        if i[0][0] != i2[0][0]
            list3.append(i2)
```

But list3 displays elements which are common

Comment: `list3 = list1 +list2` should do it, after filtering `list2`.

Comment: This post may be of help for you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logic of your attempt is wrong. Your double loop fails because when looping on all elements of both combined lists, the difference test *has* to be true at some point.

Let me propose a faster & working alternative:

- Extract the first elements of each `list1` sublists in a `set` for quick match.
- Then create new list by adding `list1` and the filtered elements of `list2`

Like this:

```
list1 = [['x1',1,'b1'],['x2',1,'b1'],['x3',1,'b1'],['x4',1,'b1']]
list2 = [['x1',0,'b1'],['x5',0,'b1'],['x2',0,'b1'],['x7',0,'b1']]

list_items = {l[0] for l in list1}

list3 = list1 + [l for l in list2 if l[0] not in list_items]
```

result:

```
>>> list3
[['x1', 1, 'b1'],
 ['x2', 1, 'b1'],
 ['x3', 1, 'b1'],
 ['x4', 1, 'b1'],
 ['x5', 0, 'b1'],
 ['x7', 0, 'b1']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jean bon nuit :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sets and make a union to eliminate duplicates:

```
list1 = [[1,1,1], [1,1,2]]
list2 = [[1,1,3], [1,1,2]]

list1 = set([tuple(x) for x in list1])
list2 = set([tuple(x) for x in list2])

res = list1.union(list2)
```

this will yield `{(1, 1, 3), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2)}`

and to have it as a list of lists you can do: `[list(x) for x in res]`

Comment: I like the idea and I was about to suggest a similar approach but the end result type for the OP is a list. So you still have to convert your final result to a list.

Comment: @perennial_noob can be done with `[list(x) for x in res]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary to merge two lists:

```
from itertools import chain

x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x7 = 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x7'
b1, b2, b3 = 'b1', 'b2', 'b3'

list1 = [[x1, 1, b1], [x2, 1, b1], [x3, 1, b1], [x4, 1, b1]]
list2 = [[x1, 0, b1], [x5, 0, b1], [x2, 0, b1], [x7, 0, b1]]

d = {i[0]: i for i in chain(list2, list1)}
sorted(d.values(), key=lambda x: x[0])
# [['x1', 1, 'b1'], ['x2', 1, 'b1'], ['x3', 1, 'b1'], ['x4', 1, 'b1'], ['x5', 0, 'b1'], ['x7', 0, 'b1']]
```

Answer (score -3):

Append the lists together, so

```
list3.append(list2)
list3.append(list1)
```