# How do I append items to a list inside a for loop in python?

Tags: python

What I want to do is take names from namelist, compare those to names in banklist, and if there is an item in banklist which looks a lot like an item in namelist, I want to append that item to a closematchlist. The goal of this is to find items that occur in both lists, even if there is a spelling error in namelist.
When I print(closematch), it works like intended: the close matches in banklist get found and printed. However, when I try to append those items to a list, the result of print(closematchlist) is [].

````
for name in namelist:
    closematch = difflib.get_close_matches(name, banklist, 1, 0.8)
    closematchlist = list()
    closematchlist.append(closematch)
    print(closematch)
print(closematchlist)```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Comment: put "closematchlist = list()" out of the for-loop

Comment: The problem is that you keep recreating closematchlist inside the loop - meaning you're emptying it on every iteration. remove the line     closematchlist = list()

Comment: This is a good use-case for a list comprehension (assuming the calls to `print` are just for debugging purposes and can be removed). `closematchlist = [difflib.get_close_matches(name, ...) for name in namelist]`.

Comment: Ahh wow Andy and Roy2012 that makes a lot of sense. I'm dumb! Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`difflib.get_close_matches()` is a list of close matches. You don't need to copy it to a new list.

Comment: The OP might want a list of those lists, or maybe use `closematchlist.extend` instead; it's not clear from the question.

Comment: That's also a great point. It was still a learning moment though! Shouldn't have put closematchlist = [] inside the for loop. Thanks for your answer!