# How to delete everything from list excluding duplicates from 2 lists?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

So i have 2 lists and i need to delete everything excluding duplicates - from both.
Example:
`a = [1,2,7,8]`
`b = [1,2,5,9]`

output:
`[1,2]`
ELSE (which is better)
`1 2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
print(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
>>> {1, 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `set`

```py
a = [1,2,7,8] 
b = [1,2,5,9]

result = list(sorted(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
```

Comment: This could be good decition,but sorting is a little bit earlier than deleting douplicates,so it shouldn't be here

Comment: @ATTMrCmailik, it depends what version of python that set will be ordered by insertion or not. That is why `sorted` is there, to keep the original order

Answer (score 1):

On top of Maurice's answer, you can avoid calling set on b as it is taken care by intersection.

```py
print(set(a).intersection(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension in this question. Like this:

```
print([i for i in a for j in b if i==j])
```