# Matching word from two separate lists

Tags: python, list, matching, cpu-word

I have two lists that need to matched:

```
List 1: Apples, Bananas, Orange, Grapes

List 2: Bananas, Pears, Kiwi, Grapes
```

I would like to find the matching words, but I don't even know where to start. I thought creating dictionaries would be a good way. However, I can't split it since it is a list. It would be really helpful if someone pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Comment: has your question been answered?

Comment: "I can't split it since it is a list." What's the data type of your lists?

Answer (score 1):

- Knowing how to compare strings and output the values from your lists are the main problems that you need to solve.
- Using for loops could be a way to check each value of your lists, and then compare each index from list 1 to list 2.
- When you are comparing the strings, you can use the == operator to see if the strings are made up of the same characters.

I would check out these sources:

- [Python String Comparison](https://www.journaldev.com/23511/python-string-comparison)
- [Python Accessing Index and Value in the List](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-accessing-index-and-value-in-list/)

hopefully that helps, and good luck with your program!

Answer (score 0):

- Create two list
- Iterate through the first list and compare every item in the first list to every item in the second list
- If the items are the same, print them

```
list_one = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Orange', 'grapes']

list_two = ['Bananas', 'pears', 'Kiwi', 'grapes']

for fruit_one in list_one:
    for fruit_two in list_two:
        if fruit_one == fruit_two:
            print(fruit_one,fruit_two)
```