# How to create a list with the elements that exist in both lists

Tags: python

```
list1 = ["aaa", "bba", "bb"]
list2 = ["aav", "bb", "ace"]
list3 = (the elements in list1 and list2) 
list4 = (the elements in list1 but not in list2)
```

So, I have 2 lists here and I want to check the elements that are in both lists and the elements that exist in list1 and not in list2

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Answer (score 3):

use [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension).

```
list3 = [item for item in list1 if item in list2]
list4 = [item for item in list1 if item not in list2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).  Like this:

```
list1 = ["aaa", "bba", "bb"]
list2 = ["aav", "bb", "ace"]
list3 = list(set(list1) & set(list2))
list4 = list(set(list1) - set(list2))
print(list3)
print(list4)
```

Or same as above, but using set functions:

```
list1 = ["aaa", "bba", "bb"]
list2 = ["aav", "bb", "ace"]
list3 = list(set(list1).intersection(set(list2))) # same as &
list4 = list(set(list1).difference(set(list2))) # same as -
print(list3)
print(list4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [8]: list1 = ["aaa", "bba", "bb"]
   ...: list2 = ["aav", "bb", "ace"]

In [9]: set(list1) & set(list2)
Out[9]: {'bb'}

In [10]: set(list1) - set(list2)
Out[10]: {'aaa', 'bba'}
```