# Comparing lists and extracting unique values

Tags: python

I have two lists:

l1: 38510 entries
l2: 6384 entries

I want to extract only values, which are present in both lists.

So far that was my approach:

```
equals = []

for quote in l2:
   for quote2 in l1:
      if quote == quote2:
         equals.append(quote)

len(equals)) = 4999
len(set(equals))) = 4452
```

First of all, I have the feeling this approach is pretty inefficient, because I am checking every value in l1 several times ..

Furthermore, it seems that I get still duplicates. Is this due to the inner-loop for l1?

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you want to extract unique values? Or values that are present in both lists? Or values that are uniquely present in both lists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `list comprehension` and the `in` operator.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 0]

[x for x in a if x in b]
#[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track by using sets. One of set's coolest features is that you can get the *intersection* between two sets. An intersection is another way to say the values that occur in both sets. You can read about it more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection)

Here is my example:

```
l1_set = set(l1)
l2_set = set(l2)

equals = l1_set & l2_set

#If you really want it as a list
equals = list(equals)

print(equals)
```

The `&` operator tells python to return a new set that only has values in both sets. At the end, I went ahead and converted equals back to a list because that's what your original example wanted. You can omit that if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

**1. This is the simplest method where we haven’t used any built-in functions.**

```py
# Two lists in most simple way of showing the intersection
def intersection(list_one, list_two):
    temp_list = [value for value in list_one if value in list_two]
    return temp_list
  
# Illustrate the intersection
list_one = [4, 9, 1, 17, 11, 26, 28, 54, 69]
list_two = [9, 9, 74, 21, 45, 11, 63, 28, 26]
print(intersection(list_one, list_two))

# [123, 3, 23, 15]
```

**2. You can use the python `set()` method.**

```py
# Two lists using set() method
def intersection(list_one, list_two):
    return list(set(list_one) & set(list_two))
  
# Illustrate the intersection
list_one = [15, 13, 123, 23, 31, 10, 3, 311, 738, 25, 124, 19]
list_two = [12, 14, 1,  15, 36, 123, 23, 3, 315, 87]
print(intersection(list_one, list_two))

# [123, 3, 23, 15]
```

**3. In this technique, we can use the built-in function called `intersection()` to compute the intersected list.**

First, we need to use `set()` for a larger list then compute the intersection.

```py
# Two lists using set() and intersection()
def intersection_list(list_one, list_two):
    return list(set(list_one).intersection(list_two))
      
# Illustrate the intersection
list_one = [15, 13, 123, 23, 31, 10, 3, 311, 738, 25, 124, 19]
list_two = [12, 14, 1,  15, 36, 123, 23, 3, 315, 87, 978, 4, 13, 19, 20, 11]

if len(list_one) < len(list_two):
    list_one, list_two = list_two, list_one
    
print(intersection_list(list_one, list_two))

# [3, 13, 15, 19, 23, 123]
```

Additional you can follow the bellow tutorials

1. [Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/)
2. [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection)
3. [LearnCodingFast](https://learncodingfast.com/how-to-find-intersection-of-two-lists-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that all the entries in both of your lists are integers. If so, computing the intersection between the 2 lists would be more efficient than using list comprehension:

```
import timeit
l1 = [i for i in range(0, 38510)]
l2 = [i for i in range(0, 6384)]

st1 = timeit.default_timer()
# Using list comprehension
l3 = [i for i in l1 if i in l2]
ed1 = timeit.default_timer()

# Using set
st2 = timeit.default_timer()
l4 = list(set(l1) & set(l2))
ed2 = timeit.default_timer()

print(ed1-st1) # 5.7621682 secs
print(ed2-st2) # 0.004478600000000554 secs
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have such long lists, you might want to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) which is specialized in providing efficient list processing for Python.

You can enjoy the fast processing with its numpy function.  For your case, you can use [`numpy.intersect1d()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to get the sorted, unique values that are in both of the input arrays, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1, 3, 5, 10, 11, 12]
l2 = [2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]

l_uniques = np.intersect1d(l1, l2)


print(l_uniques)

[ 3 10 12]
```

You can keep the resulting list as numpy array for further fast processing or further convert it back to Python list by:

```
l_uniques2 = l_uniques.tolist()
```