# What is the use of pop in a list comprehension finding the common part of two lists?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm a beginner in python and found this list comprehension

```
l2, common = l2[:], [ e for e in l1 if e in l2 and (l2.pop(l2.index(e)) or True)]
```

in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542432/5267751) to a question about how to find the common elements in two lists(question: [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists) ).

What does the `l2.pop` part do? Is it there just to check if the element exists or is the removing part of `pop()` important too? Thank you in advance

Comment: That's definitely bad practice the linked answer uses... (although it's *allowed* to ask about how an existing answer works)

Comment: ```if e in l2 and (l2.pop(l2.index(e)) or True)```? ```or True```? That is always True

Comment: @Sujay ... to clarify, it's not code OP wrote themselves, they're asking how the other SO answer linked works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was mentioned by @user202729 above, this code represents a practice that should be avoided, since it modifies a mutable object (the list `l2`) in place inside a list comprehension and uses side effects of this modification. It is easy to make mistakes writing code like this and it may be difficult to spot these mistakes.

In any case, the goal is to create a list `common` which consists of elements that are common to both `l1` and `l2`. Moreover, if some element appears n times in both lists, then it will be listed n times in `common`.

The code uses the fact that Python evaluates logical expressions lazily.
In the conditon

```
if e in l2 and ((l2.pop(l2.index(e)) or True)
```

the first part `e in l2` is evaluated first. If it gives `False` i.e. the element `e` of `l1` is not in `l2`, then the part after `and` is not executed, `e` is not included in `common`, and the list comprehension moves on to the next element of `l1`.

On the other hand, if `e in l2` evaluates to `True`, then the part after `and` gets evaluated. The value of this part is always `True` (due to the `or True` bit), so `e` becomes an element of `common`. However, Python first runs `l2.pop(l2.index(e))` which removes one occurrence of the element `e` from the list `l2`. For this reason, if the iteration encounters the same element `e` in the list `l1` again, then this element will be included in `common` for the second time only if it appears in `l2` also more than once.

Comment: It's also needlessly complicated, could use `[l2.remove(e) or e for e in l1 if e in l2]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy. Sure, or `[l2.pop(l2.index(e)) for e in l1 if e in l2]`.

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, the return from pop doesn't actually do anything and any function that'll remove e from l2 could actually do?

Comment: @fairykingoberon Yes, the return from `pop` is not used. You could write a function that removes an element from  `l2` and returns an object with no True/False value, and such a function would not work here. But aside from such contrived examples, any function would do.

Comment: *"such a function would not work"* - Why not? Can you show such a function?

Comment: @KellyBundy The return value is used to evaluate a boolean expression, so it needs to have an associated boolean value. As an example of something that will not work, you can write a function that removes an element of `l2` but returns some numpy array with more than one element.

Comment: Ah, no truth value, raising an error. Naming "True/False" misled me. Good example. Though now I'm wondering whether ["Any object can be tested for truth value"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) should be rephrased. Oh well.