# Developing an algorithm with O(mlogn) complexity

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search, time-complexity

I am struggling to find the exact solution for this question.

A university has two student clubs. The number of students registered to the first club is m and their IDs are stored in an array A (with m elements) whereas the number of students registered to the second club is n and their IDs are stored in an array B (with n elements), where m≤n. A student might be registered to either one of these clubs or both. We want to decide how many students are registered to both clubs.
Given two arrays A and B along with their lenghts m and n, write a O(mlogn) algorithm (as a pseudocode) to find the number of elements that are registered to both clubs. For example, when A is [2, 6, 3, 9, 11, 8] and B is [3, 11, 7, 4, 2, 5, 1], the algorithm must return 3 corresponding to the students with IDs 2, 3 and 11.Explain why your running time is O(mlogn) in sufficient detail.

First thing that comes to my mind is sorting the array B and then searching match for each element in B from A. Sorting O(nlogn), looking for match O(mlogn) then the conluded result becomes O((m+n)logn).

Second way on my mind was to merge the arrays then look for the duplicates but idk.

Comment: *"Inside your pseudocode, you are allowed to use functions that are already defined in class videos, slides and book."* Looks like you are way ahead of us! We didn't follow that class :(

Comment: If you need a solution that works out of the box, you can try to take a look for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists If you want to understand how does it work then you have to read your book.

Comment: `n` could be much bigger than `m logn`, and you have to examine all elements of `B`. So, I can't see how it is possible...are you allowed to use hashing?

Comment: Are you sure they want you to do it in m log(n) and not n log(m) ? That would be much easier

Comment: Also can you assume that the arrays are already sorted? In that case it could be done in m log(n) easily.

Comment: Well we are having the hardest time in class because of these kind of questions :(

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with the question.

If B starts sorted, there is a `O(m log(n))` algorithm.

If neither is sorted, there is a `O(n log(m))` algorithm.

But if neither is sorted, you cannot even search B once without taking time `O(n)`.  And `O(m log(n))` needs to run faster than that in the limit where `m` goes to infinity while `n = m^2`.

Comment: How does it become O(n log(m)) if neither is sorted?

Comment: @atakatom Because (n+m) log(m) = O(n log(m)) since m = O(n)

Comment: @atakatom Sort A, do a binary search of A for each element of B.  Worst case O(n log(m)).  If you hash A instead you'll get an average case of O(n).