# find common and duplicate items of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists :

```
v = ['bus','car','person','bus']
vehicles=['car','bus','truck','motorcycle','auto-rickshaw']
```

I need a list M which should compare list `v` with `vehicles` and results like

```
M = ['car', 'bus', 'bus']
```

Please help and suggest.
I have referred [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists) but it doesn't answers my question.

Comment: The intersection of two lists is exactly what you want. What results does the answer in the linked post return you, which is wrong?

Comment: Is the order important?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Desired output is `[car, bus, bus]` linked question uses sets to solve which removes duplicate values.

Comment: @Ch3 Not all the answers use sets https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385567/2308683

Comment: `O(n^2)` solution though @OneCricketeer OP did not comment about efficiency in this question but this question can be answered in `O(n)` like mozway did. Much better IMO than the linked answer and I believe it would useful to future readers(Assuming a duplicate doesn't exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If order doesn't matter (or rather, if you want to keep the order in `v`), use a list comprehension with a set as reference for efficient identification of members (O(1) per item in `v`, so O(n) in total):

```
v = ['bus','car','person','bus']
vehicles=['car','bus','truck','motorcycle','auto-rickshaw']

ref = set(vehicles)

M = [e for e in v if e in ref]
```

output: `['bus', 'car', 'bus']`

If really you want to have the order of `vehicles`, sorting afterwards is probably the most efficient:

```
order = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(vehicles)}
M2 = sorted(M, key=order.get)
```

output:

```
['car', 'bus', 'bus']
```