# How to find common values in 2 dictionaries of the same key

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1={1:["solomon", "Daniel", " taiwo", "David"], 2:["James", "Jason", " abbaly"], 3:["Sarah", "Abraham", "Johnson"]}

dict2={1:["ire", "kehinde", " taiwo", "David"], 2:["jah", "abbey", " abbaly"], 3:["sarai", "Abraham", "Johnson"]}
```

I want to find all common words in dict1[key] and dict2[same_key].

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: what happend when dictionary1  and 2 has same values 2 times eg `dictp[1]=["solomon", "Daniel", " taiwo", "David", "David"]` and    d`ict2=["ire", "kehinde", " taiwo", "David"]`, what should be output then ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `dict1` and `dict2` have the same keys, we can use a dictionary comprehension and the set intersection operator to do the following:

```py
dict1={1:["solomon", "Daniel", " taiwo", "David"], 2:["James", "Jason", " abbaly"], 3:["Sarah", "Abraham", "Johnson"]}

dict2={1:["ire", "kehinde", " taiwo", "David"], 2:["jah", "abbey", " abbaly"], 3:["sarai", "Abraham", "Johnson"]}

print({key: list(set(dict1[key]) & set(dict2[key])) for key in dict1.keys()})
```

This comprehension can be further improved by doing the following (thanks Jon Clements!):

```py
print({k: list(set(v).intersection(dict2[k])) for k, v in dict1.items()})
```

Comment: Note this can be written as `{k: list(set(v).intersection(dict2[k])) for k, v in dict1.items()}`  avoiding an unnecessary lookup for dict1's value and an unnecessary conversion to set for dict2 values...

Comment: Edited into original post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in dict1:
    if key in dict2:
        print(word for word in dict1[key] if word in dict2[key])
```