# What can I use for finding names words in two list? Python

Tags: python

I am interested in the finding of the same words in two lists. I have two lists of words in the text_list I also stemmed the words.

```
text_list = [['i', 'am', 'interest' ,'for', 'this', 'subject'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'second', 'sentence']]
words_list = ['a', 'word', 'sentence', 'interesting']
```

So I need this output:

```
same_words= ['a', 'sentence', 'interest']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Common elements comparison between 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864842/common-elements-comparison-between-2-lists)

Comment: Is `"interest"` and `"interesting"` supposed to be considered the same?

Comment: Yes, it is the same word, but a different grammatical form, that's why I am searching for an approach in Python, that can return 'interest' and 'interesting' like a same word.

Comment: "I also stemmed the words." What exactly do you mean by this? It doesn't look in the example data as if anything like that happened.

Comment: Sounds fuzzywuzzy to me. ; )

Comment: @Rina, see if this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825908/16836078

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply stemming to both the lists, There are discrepancies for example `interesting` and `interest` and if you apply stemming to only `words_list` then `Sentence` becomes `sentenc` so, therefore, apply stemmer to both the lists and then find the common elements:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

text_list = [['i', 'am', 'interest','for', 'this', 'subject'], ['this', 'is', 'a', 'second', 'sentence']]
words_list = ['a', 'word', 'sentence', 'interesting']

ps = PorterStemmer()
words_list = [ps.stem(w) for w in words_list]
text_list = [list(map(ps.stem,i)) for i in text_list]

answer = []
for i in text_list:
    answer.append(list(set(words_list).intersection(set(i))))

output = sum(answer, [])
print(output)

>>> ['interest', 'a', 'sentenc']
```

Comment: I have an error "object of type 'float' has no let(). It seems like somewhere in the data is a number. How can I fix it?

Comment: use regex to handle numbers in your data. `re.sub()` will substitute the digits, or you can drop all those data points that have floats

Comment: May I ask You, for what is the square bracket after the answer in the output line?

Comment: `answer = []` ? I'm just initializing the answer array

Comment: No this one: output = sum(answer, [])

Comment: @Rina that is to make a flattened 1d list

Answer (score 0):

There is a package called `fuzzywuzzy` which allows you to match the string from a list with the strings from another list with approximation.

First of all, you will need to flatten your nested list to a list/set with unique strings.

```
from itertools import chain
newset =  set(chain(*text_list))

{'sentence', 'i', 'interest', 'am', 'is', 'for', 'a', 'second', 'subject', 'this'}
```

Next, from the `fuzzywuzzy` package, we import the `fuzz` function.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

result = [max([(fuzz.token_set_ratio(i,j),j) for j in newset]) for i in words_list]

[(100, 'a'), (57, 'for'), (100, 'sentence'), (84, 'interest')]
```

by looking at here, the `fuzz.token_set_ratio` actually helps you to match the every element from the `words_list` to all the elements in `newset` and gives the percentage of matching alphabets between the two elements. You can remove the `max` to see the full list of it. (Some alphabets in `for` is in the `word`, that's why it's shown in this tuple list too with 57% of matching. You can later use a for loop and a percentage tolerance to remove those matches below the percentage tolerance)

Finally, you will use `map` to get your desired output.

```
similarity_score, fuzzy_match = map(list,zip(*result))

fuzzy_match
Out[40]: ['a', 'for', 'sentence', 'interest']
```

### Extra

If your input is not the usual ASCII standard, you can put another argument in the `fuzz.token_set_ratio`

```
a = ['У', 'вас', 'є', 'чашка', 'кави?']

b = ['ви']

[max([(fuzz.token_set_ratio(i, j, force_ascii= False),j) for j in a]) for i in b]
Out[9]: [(67, 'кави?')]
```

Comment: `for` is not in the expected output.

Comment: Hey, this approach looks very interesting, I tried the code with result and unfortunately it is going an hour in the Jupiter notebook. I am just a beginner in the programming, but maybe it is possible to check in this code, if it is a finite loop?

Comment: @darthbaba yes, but I am just showing the usage of the `fuzzywuzzy`. For the `for` , we can see that it has low percentage of matches, so we can make another loop function to remove low percentage matching words.

Comment: @Rina how many words do you have in your original lists?

Comment: 4679 words in the words_list

Comment: Try to change the newset to words_list and the words_list to newset when doing the list tuple comprehension

Comment: @Rina I have tried with 10000 words, and it still runs very fast. Perhaps try it in Python and see how it goes

Comment: Is it language sensitive? Because I am working with Ukrainian alphabetic

Comment: Yes apparently Not all the alphabets are supported in this package. However, you can add another arg - `force_ascii = False`. See if it works for you

Comment: Where in the code should I place it?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check it. Thank you